# Flutter: How to solve type 'List<NetworkImage>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, carousel

When i am trying to run the code for connecting carousel with Firestore
the error is showing like this '' 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' '' or if there is any other way to connect cloud firestore with carousel images so that i can change my images using firestore.

```
class About extends StatelessWidget {

   List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];

 @override        
 Widget build(BuildContext context)     {
 
SizeConfig().init(context);
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'About',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Colors.black, //change your color here
    ),
  ),
  body:     ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5,
            top: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5,
            right: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 80,
            height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 100,
            
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('About').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      _listOfImages = [];
                      for (int i = 0;
                          i < snapshot.data.documents[index].data['image'].length;
                          i++
                          )
                           {
                        _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(snapshot
                            .data.documents[index].data['image'][i]));
                      }
            return Carousel(
              boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
              dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
              dotIncreasedColor: Colors.grey,
              dotSize: 6.0,
              images: [
               _listOfImages
              
              ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing that error as you already have declared

`List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];`

which mens `_listOfImages` have `List` type of `NetworkImage`

And you need to pass `List` type to parameter to `images` argument in your `Carousel` widget.

So you are doing it as

```
images: [
     _listOfImages
],
```

Mens you are passing 2D array in that argument by mistake.

Please just pass `images: _listOfImages`, and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this instead..

```
images: _listOfImages,
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove [ ] from image : [ _listOfImages ];
do this instead

```
return Carousel(
          boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
          dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
          dotIncreasedColor: Colors.grey,
          dotSize: 6.0,
          images:
           _listOfImages,
          );
```